# Javascript Time convert to Java SimpleDateformat - Missing Digit in Day

Tags: javascript

Hello I am needing to take a data/time format in a certain way - `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`

I am nearly there but I seem to be missing a digit off my result.

My result is showing `YYYY-MM-DTHH:MM:SS` can anyone see where I have gone wrong, or how I can fix this? - Thanks

**HTML**

```
<button id="showit">show</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**JS**

```
Number.prototype.padLeft = function(base,chr){
       var  len = (String(base || 10).length - String(this).length)+1;
       return len > 0? new Array(len).join(chr || '0')+this : this;
    }


    $('#showit').click(function(){
        var d = new Date,
            dformat = [ (d.getFullYear()+0),
                        d.getMonth(),
                        d.getDate()].join('-')+
                        'T' +
                      [ d.getHours().padLeft(),
                        d.getMinutes().padLeft(),
                        d.getSeconds().padLeft()].join(':');
         $('#result').html(dformat);
    });
```

Comment: You need to do your padLeft function on the date. And on the month come January (remember that dates are a zero-based array, which is why your program shows "10" currently in November).

Comment: d.getFullYear().padLeft()+0),
                    d.getMonth().padLeft(),
                    d.getDate().padLeft()].join('-')

That fixed the day, thank you. But month still shows as 10! I didn't spot that before